# multithreading with opm what's wrong?

Tags: c, openmp

I had a question on my exam but i didnt understand what they wanted from me.

Here are lines of code which has some mistakes but i didn't get it.

```
int a = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
 a++;}
```

Actually, i'm thinking about a, as for me a must be inside of threads.

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `a++` operation is not atomic. I guess you should have learnt this term through your course, alternatively you can look up the definition on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_operation).

Comment: so would it be correct if i'd use `#pragma omp atomic for` for `a++` ?